# Grails/GGTS: compilation gives org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space/GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a 2.2.4 Grails project with ***lots*** of Domain classes (~360) and I am using GGTS 3.3.0.

These 360 domain classes where generated by reverse engineering plugin.

The problem is that I can't compile my project in GGTS, receiving

```
Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I have a Win7 system with 6GB RAM running the most updated release of Oracle JDK 1.6

Any clues on how to configure GGTS in order to permit me compiling the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add memory to your JVM! That should help (adding options to VM):

```
-Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Comment: you mean in GGTS.ini? or in GGTS preferences in Grails Launcher? And if it is the Grails Launcher, should it be in Grails env or Java env? Sorry for the many questions, but there are so many JAVA_OPTS places to edit in theory and I am confused...

Comment: I think you should add to Grail Launcher in STS

Comment: I belive @Xilang is right. But you can add this options to Grails env and it will work for you too.